# Swift Xcode6B3 - Byte Swapping - Undefined symbol "__OSSwapInt16"

Tags: xcode, linker, swift

I wanted to use the Swift method `CFSwapInt16BigToHost` but I can't get it linking. I link against the CoreFoundation framework, but every time I get the following error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "__OSSwapInt16", referenced from:
```

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, for some reason the `CFSwap...` functions cannot be used in a Swift program.

But since Xcode 6 beta 3, all integer types have `little/bigEndian:` constructors
and `little/bigEndian` properties.
From the `UInt16` struct definition:

```
/// Creates an integer from its big-endian representation, changing the
/// byte order if necessary.
init(bigEndian value: UInt16)

/// Creates an integer from its little-endian representation, changing the
/// byte order if necessary.
init(littleEndian value: UInt16)

/// Returns the big-endian representation of the integer, changing the
/// byte order if necessary.
var bigEndian: UInt16 { get }

/// Returns the little-endian representation of the integer, changing the
/// byte order if necessary.
var littleEndian: UInt16 { get }
```

Example:

```
// Data buffer containing the number 1 in 16-bit, big-endian order:
var bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x00, 0x01]
let data = NSData(bytes: &bytes, length: bytes.count)

// Read data buffer into integer variable:
var i16be : UInt16 = 0
data.getBytes(&i16be, length: sizeofValue(i16be))
println(i16be) // Output: 256

// Convert from big-endian to host byte-order:
let i16 = UInt16(bigEndian: i16be)
println(i16) // Output: 1
```

---

*Update:* As of Xcode 6.1.1, the `CFSwap...` functions are available in Swift, so

```
let i16 = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(bigEndian: i16be)
let i16 = UInt16(bigEndian: i16be)
```

*both* work, with identical results.

Comment: A precision missed in my post. I wanted to swap byte from bigendian to host !

Comment: @yageek: `let x = UInt16(bigEndian: y)` does the same as `x = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(y)` . Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those are handled with a combination of macro's and inline functions so... I don't know why it wouldn't be already statically compiled into the CF version:

generally to solve this kind of dependency riddle you can just search for the naked function name without prefixed underscores, then figure out where it should be linked from

```
#define OSSwapInt16(x)  __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x)
```

then

```
#define __DARWIN_OSSwapInt16(x) \
((__uint16_t)(__builtin_constant_p(x) ? __DARWIN_OSSwapConstInt16(x) : _OSSwapInt16(x)))
```

then

```
__DARWIN_OS_INLINE
__uint16_t
_OSSwapInt16(
    __uint16_t        _data
)
{
    return ((__uint16_t)((_data << 8) | (_data >> 8)));
}
```

I know this isn't a real answer but it was too big for a comment, 
I think you may need to find out if there is a problem with the way that swift imports the headers... like if for instance the macro's to import headers isn't correct in a swift setup.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, the __OSSwapInt16 swap method does not appear to be in the swift header of the CFByte framework. I think the swift like alternative would be:

```
var dataLength: UInt16 = 24
var swapped = UInt16(dataLength).byteSwapped
```